# Unix - prepare dump file for another environment

Tags: unix, sed, gzip, gunzip

I'm working on a project with a friend of mine and we installed two systems, one for production and one for test. The development environment uses the same database name as the productive environment so I can import the dump directly there, but as the test environment is hosted using another database  name I have to change the name within the dump file.

As the dump file is quite big and I'm too lazy I'd like to have a script or a one line command that

1. unzip the latest *.gz file in the specific folder
2. replaces all occurances of db1 to db2
3. zips the sql file using the same filename as in 1. but with the suffix "test_" (or anything else)

After the script has run I'd like to have the original dump file AND the new one for the test environment. I don't need the unzip sql file, only the zips. Until now I came up with something like

```
gunzip -c `ls -t *.gz | head -1` | sed -i 's/db1/db2/g' `ls -t *.sql | head -1` | gzip `ls -t *.sql | head -1` test_`ls -t *.gz | head -1`
```

But I always end up with sed complaining about finding no input files??

Anyone who can help me with this? as mentioned I don't care if it's a script or a one line command using pipes as long as it works ;-)

Comment: I do suggest that you do not use old and deprecated back tics.  It makes the line very hard to read.  Do use parentheses like this instead: `gunzip -c $(ls -t *.gz | head -1) | sed -i 's/db1/db2/g' $(ls -t *.sql | head -1) | gzip $(ls -t *.sql | head -1) test_$(ls -t *.gz | head -1)`

Comment: I didn't get that backtips are deprecated, I really appreciate it

Comment: `sed -i` doesn't make much sense on a pipe.  Are you thinking `-i` is case insensitive or something?  It tells sed to edit the input file in place.  Hence, it's griping that there are no input *files*, only a pipe.